# How do I utilize $.Deferred() / Promise() properly in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, promise, jquery-deferred

The problem with this as tested in the debugger, is that it will go in the first function (up to the `$.get()` without actually getting anything yet) then skip into the second function (once again, up to the `$.get()`). Then, it will proceed to execute the first function till it's finished retrieving all items, then when it gets into the second function, it will do the same thing but for some mysterious reason, the videoIdChainStr which holds all the video ids in a string from the first function is never retrieved or being executed since I suspected, it executed the second function's $.`get(...)` already and never did it again a "second time" when it had the values. To resolve that, I thought of async operations and it's a bit confusing at first but after reading some articles, I understand some, but not 100%, and especially not in code yet, but I tried the code below:

I want to really understand how to use $.Deferred, resolve(), and promise() in this case and if applicable, the other methods like then(), since I only need a resolve and promise to return a filled value (`videoIdChainStr`) to the done() that is needed and executes the second function thereafter.

**First Function:**

```
var relatedVidsDefer = function relatedVids(videoId)
{
    var videoIdChainStr = null;
    var deferredVal = $.Deferred(); // instantiate defer object

    $.get( // get related videos related to videoId
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",
        {
            part: 'snippet',
            maxResults: vidResults,
            relatedToVideoId: videoId,
            order: 'relevance',
            type: 'video',
            key: 'XXXXXXX'
        },

        function(data)
        {
            $.each(data.items,
                function(i, item)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        console.log(item);
                        var vidTitle = item.snippet.title; // video title

                        var vidThumbUrl = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url; 
                        var channelTitle = item.snippet.channelTitle;
                        var extractVideoId = null; // var to extract video id string from vidThumbUrl

                        // check if vidThumbUrl is not null, empty string, or undefined
                        if(vidThumbUrl)
                        {
                            var split = vidThumbUrl.split("/"); // split string when '/' seen
                            extractVideoId = split[4]; // retrieve the fourth index on the fourth '/'
                        }
                        else console.error("vidThumbUrl is either undefined or null or empty string.");

                        // if video title is longer than 25 characters, insert the three-dotted ellipse
                        if(vidTitle.length > 25)
                        {
                            var strNewVidTitle = vidTitle.substr(0, 25) + "...";
                            vidTitle = strNewVidTitle;
                        }





                        // check whether channelTitle is the same
                        if(channelTitle === "Channel Name")
                        {
                            extractedVideoIdArr.push(extractVideoId); // add the extracted video id to the array

                            // check if extractedVideoIdArr is not empty
                            if(extractedVideoIdArr !== 'undefined' && extractedVideoIdArr.length > 0)
                            {
                                videoIdChainStr = extractedVideoIdArr.join(", "); // change from an array to a chain string of videoIds for the relatedVidsDetails() 
                            }
                            deferredVal.resolve(videoIdChainStr); // get the value


                            var vidThumbnail = '<div class="video-thumbnail"><a class="thumb-link" href="single-video.html"><div class="video-overlay"><img src="imgs/video-play-button.png"/></div><img src="' + vidThumbUrl + '" alt="No Image Available." style="width:204px;height:128px"/></a><p><a class="thumb-link" href="single-video.html">' + vidTitle + '</a><br/></div>';

                            // print results
                            $('.thumb-related').append(vidThumbnail);
                            $(item).show(); // show current video thumbnail item 
                        }
                        else $(item).hide(); // hide current video thumbnail item
                    }
                    catch(err)
                    {
                        console.error(err.message); // log error but continue operation    
                    }
                }
            ); 
        }
    );
    return deferredVal.promise(); // return the value and execute the second function
};
```

**Second Function:**

```
var relatedVidsDetailsDefer = function relatedVidsDetails(videoIdChainStr)
{
    // change extractvideoid into a string by tostring() or join() for param to recognize
    console.log("initial: ", extractedVideoIdArr);
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",
        {
            part: 'snippet, contentDetails, statistics',
            id: videoIdChainStr, // chain string of video ids to be called upon in a single request
            key: 'XXXXXXX',
        },

        function(data)
        {
            $.each(data.items,
                function(i, item)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var _vidDuration = item.contentDetails.duration;
                        var _viewCount = item.statistics.viewCount;
                        console.log("id: " + extractedVideoIdArr[i] + " duration: " + _vidDuration);
                        console.log("id: " + extractedVideoIdArr[i] + " viewCount: " + _viewCount);

                        $('.vidDetails').append(convert_time(_vidDuration) + ' / Views: ' + _viewCount);
                    }
                    catch(err)
                    {
                        console.error(err.message); // log error but continue operation    
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    );
};
```

**Execution:**

```
relatedVidsDefer(_videoId).done(relatedVidsDetailsDefer); // wait till first function (before .done parameter) is complete before executing the second (in .done paramater)
```

**Update:**

Code Updated with @valarauko's answer. Finally, it worked and was able to retrieve the videos' details for one of the videos that duplicated to the rest of the videos. Upon entering the second function, `videoIdChainStr` only has the first id and not the rest... which I'm assuming, `deferredVal.resolve(videoIdChainStr);` will resolve right away when it gets an id the first time in the first function's loop, but not the rest of the string, even though it continues to loop and resolve all the items.

For Example:
Suppose to pass `ID1, ID2, ID3` to parameter, but only passed `ID1`. Thus why it only went through the each loop on the second function once. How do I fix this occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the second function is executing before is because you are appending the parenthesis to the function inside the done statement (this executes inmediately the function and assigns the result of the function in the done callback.

```
relatedVidsDefer(_videoId).done(relatedVidsDetailsDefer());
```

should be

```
relatedVidsDefer(_videoId).done(relatedVidsDetailsDefer);
```

Also I don't know if you are using the videoIdChainStr a global variable on purpose but I would recommend you to make it locally and feed relatedVidsDetailsDefer a function that receives the parameter (no change should be done to the first function since you are already resolving the promise with that string.

The second function would be like

```
var relatedVidsDetailsDefer = function relatedVidsDetails(videoIdChainStr) {...}
```

**UPDATE**

If you look at the jQuery deferred documentation ([link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/)), a resolved/rejected promise will ignore future calls to resolve/reject and return the data used on the first resolved/rejected. Also notice that you had only one done statement so you were only checking for the first one anyway.

For your particular problem you can modify the second function to receive an array of strings and resolve the promise with the array of strings.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it! I put the `deferredVal.resolve(videoIdChainStr);` just after the each function and that solved it.